# CasperJS cannot obtain IP without other useless data

Tags: javascript, string, casperjs, stringify

I have now update the CasperJS script see below

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://whatismyipaddress.com/', function() {
    if (this.exists('#section_left > div:nth-child(2)')) {
        var data = this.getElementInfo('#section_left > div:nth-child(2)');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.text));
    }
});

casper.run();
```

How to I remove the `"` and `\n` and `\t` from the result I get below.

```
"\n\n23.221.147.202\n\n\t\t\t\t\t"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.text` is a single string. Stringifying a string leads to escaping whitespace and addition of quotation marks. Don't stringify a string:

```
console.log(data.text);
```

If you actually want to remove the whitespace, there is the string function `trim()`:

```
console.log(data.text.trim());
```

Comment: update your answer to this i used your answerr and modified it to work how i needed  -----  console.log(data.text.trim());